# How to run startx as non-root?

Tags: x11, xauth

Recently, I switched from Ubuntu to Arch Linux. I've installed X11 as my Window System and KDE as my Desktop Environment. I've separate partition for `/home`, `/var`, `/` and `/boot` and they all mount at boot time. When I run `startx`, the following message gets displayed.

`xauth:timeout in locking authority file /home/hello/.Xauthority`

Accidently, I've deleted that file. So, I copied it from `/root`. I've changed it's authority using code below:

`# chown hello:users ~/.Xauthority`

Even after this, I'm unable to run `startx` unless I use root account.

Comment: Copying the file is a security risk. You changed its permissions (ownership), not its authority.

Comment: (Re)move ~/.Xauthority and try `startx` again. Does it work? If not, what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First a clarification, `X` is *not* a [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), it is a [windowing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system).

Now, the `~/.Xauthority` file is simply where the identification credentials for the current user's `X`session are stored, it is the file read when the system needs to determine if you have the right to use the current `X` session.

You should never copy an existing one from another account, the file should always belong to the user running `X` and is created automatically when you start a new `X` session. So, just delete the one you have, and then run `startx` again, everything should work as normal:

```
$ rm ~/.Xauthority; startx
```

Comment: Tredon, even after removing .Xauthority file. I am unable to starx.
It keeps on displaying that same error.

Comment: @Habi you need to make sure there are no running X sessions, then remove the file, then run `startx` again.

Comment: Now, X runs but displays another message
Call to Inusertemp failed(temporary directories full?). Check your installation.

Comment: @Habi ah, good, that's progress :). Please post another question for this since it is a completely different problem. In the new question, show us the output of `df -h` and also make sure this problem is still there after restarting.

Answer (score 5):

I think an issue is that people login as root, then switch users using `su -l username`, which creates/spawns a subprocess under root owned by "username". X will use the `.Xauthority` of the top process (in this case root), which "username" does not have permission to use.

The error will be shown:

```
Cannot open virtual console 1 (Permission denied).
```

To solve this, just run `login` instead of `su` to start a new shell as a top process.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this on a Lenovo IdeaPad with two graphic cards, one from Intel the other from Nvidia.

The error resulting from `startx` included this line:

> addscreen/screeninit failed for driver 0 kde plasma

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250892#p1886416) was the solution:

1. Change `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` by adding `MODULES=(nouveau)`
2. `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux`
3. reboot